# External monitor resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: 11.10, resolution, monitor

I have an HP-Compaq 615 laptop that I connect up with an external 1440x900 monitor so that I can work with two screens. I was unable to get it to work correctly under Natty. However, when I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Oneiric 64-bit, I expected no problems when connecting up my second monitor...

However, no matter what I do, I cannot set the resolution any higher than 1024x768, even though the monitor's max resolution is 1440x900.

Google searches have only been taking me to posts telling me to use the now-defuct xorg.conf which is useless, or to use various xrandr commands, which only give me error messages.

Does anyone know how to get Ubuntu to recognize and use the monitor's real resolution? I am not using the proprietary fglrx driver because the laptop is much faster on the open-source driver.

Comment: did you try switching to the propietary driver to see if it worked then?  You can always disable it back.

Comment: @Marlon Quote: [...] I am not using the proprietary fglrx driver because the laptop is much faster on the open-source driver.[...]

Comment: @Uri Herrera I read that part and that's why I suggested "switching" to the fglrx to see if that fixed the issue.  He could switch back and see if it was working correctly and if it didn't work with fglrx then at least we know it's not because he is using the open driver.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)